# If someone finds a patent by doing a search on Google Patents, can the searcher make hyperlinks for retrieving the same patent on a different site?

Tags: search, google-patents

If someone does a search on Google Patents and the search results include a patent that is of interest to the searcher and/or relevant to the search, would the Google Patents service legally permit the searcher to record the patent’s number and to make available hyperlinks to allow others to access the same patent via a different Web site (such as the USPTO Web site)?

On a related note, if someone does multiple searches on Google Patents and the searcher finds a few patents that are of interest and relevance, would the Google Patents service legally permit the searcher to record the numbers for the patents and to make available hyperlinks to allow others to access the same patents via a different Web site (such as the USPTO Web site)?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of your very recent question.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I think the difference is the OP is interjecting Google Patents in the process of sharing links.

Comment: People link to Google Patents all the time in StackExchange without problems. In any case, you might find some useful info on Google's terms site: https://policies.google.com/terms

Comment: @EricS I have looked at the Google Terms of Service. The situation I am thinking of is: Someone does a search on Google Patents and finds a patent. The person then posts a link on SE to that patent but the link is for accessing the same patent on the USPTO's [Patent Public Search](https://ppubs.uspto.gov/pubwebapp/static/pages/landing.html) Web site system instead of Google Patents.

Comment: Why should Google care if you post a link to a website that isn’t Google? They don’t own the content at the USPTO.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer. However, I can't conceive any possibility that Google would object to a person linking to a non-Google site based on non copyrighted information gained at a Google site. Just because you may search for a patent on Google Patents, doesn't mean Google now owns all future activities to said patent by you or anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - google patents is no different than other google search facilities. If you googled Italian restaurants in your town would you wonder if google allowed you to share the links ?

Comment: A clarification: If an individual or other party does a search on Google Patents and finds a patent, would Google be okay with the searcher creating and sharing a hyperlink that would allow the same patent to be accessed via the USPTO’s [Patent Public Search](https://ppubs.uspto.gov/pubwebapp/static/pages/landing.html) Web site system instead of Google Patents?

Comment: @Richard I can’t think of a scenario where Google would think it owns the future actions of a user.